# The named parameter 'tagsList' isn't defined

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

> The named parameter 'tagsList' isn't defined. Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'tagsList'.

Here is the issues -

```
Expanded(child: SingleChildScrollView(child: Html(data: specification,
          tagsList: Html.tags,
          customRenders: {
            tableMatcher(): tableRender(),
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';
import 'package:flutter_html_table/flutter_html_table.dart';

import 'package:eamar_user_app/localization/language_constrants.dart';
import 'package:eamar_user_app/view/basewidget/custom_app_bar.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class SpecificationScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String specification;
  SpecificationScreen({required this.specification});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();


    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(children: [

        CustomAppBar(title: getTranslated('specification', context)),

        Expanded(child: SingleChildScrollView(child: Html(data: specification,
          tagsList: Html.tags,
          customRenders: {
            tableMatcher(): tableRender(),
          },
          style: {
            "table": Style(
              backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(0x50, 0xee, 0xee, 0xee),
            ),
            "tr": Style(
              border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
            ),
            "th": Style(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
            ),
            "td": Style(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            ),

          },),)),

      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hm, looking [at the API](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_html/latest/flutter_html/Html-class.html) it seems `tagsList` exists... but your `customRenders` property seems wrong, there's only `customRender`, try changing that!